# accessing 'User-Defined' xcode variables from within React Native

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a react native project I'm building with xcode. There are two targets I build for, one for staging, and one for production. And I'm managing some variables in xcode, using the 'User-Defined' section under 'Build Settings' on my various build targets.

My question is... how do I access this data from within my js in my react native app?

Answer (score 1):

Add a new entry to your Info.plist with `$(YOUR_USER_DEFINED_VALUE)` as its value. This will be replaced with the targets configured value during the build.

In AppDelegate

```
NSDictionary* info = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
NSDictionary *initialProps = @{@"yourValue" : [info valueForKey:@"NAME_IN_PLIST"]};
...
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                    moduleName:@"AppName"
                                             initialProperties:initialProps
                                                 launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

Comment: I solved it this way:   ```NSString *variableName = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"KEY_NAME_FROM_PLIST_FILE"];```